# Is it possible to host a website that is coded in one document?

Tags: javascript, html, css, host

I have a single HTML document that contains Javascript, CSS, HTML. I have no resources so I do not need any of those files. I have tried hosting it by putting the file in google drive, and doing it that way, but it did not work. Is it possible to do this or do I need to change my format.

Comment: There are many options. Googledrive used to have this feature but it was removed. Despite of that it is actually still possible to host html or js files there if you use appsscript to make a webapp. In some very simple cases even jsfiddle can be an acceptable host. (not for anything important though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to host your website - you need a server. You can't do this with google drive. Drop box did let you do this but i think the service was stopped. There are plenty of free options, You would need to sign up for a free account and then upload your html file. They would give you a URL, or you could attach a custom domain that you buy.

A service such as this is:

https://www.netlify.com/

Quick start:

https://www.netlify.com/docs/

Comment: It asks for me to upload a folder though and I only have one document

Comment: I also tried googledrive but it did not seem to work

Comment: If you mean that netlify requests a folder just pop your page in a folder call it website.

Comment: when I upload it it says page not found

Comment: page would need to be index.html inside the web folder

Comment: do I need to use new site from git

Comment: I you use a git repo then you can just drop your page index.html in to the repo and push - you need to add the repo to your netlify site and it will sync instantly.

Comment: You don't need to use git. Just upload your html file e.g with `netlify deploy`. That's all.

Comment: I get the same problem

Comment: your uploading a single folder with one file inside the file is index.html correct?

Comment: Look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7pCcE3vm5k
btw. it is also possible to host html files on github. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jt-J4Rc__M

Comment: You have checked the deploys tab - checked the folder deployed no errors and is served in the control panel?